# Angular *ngIf Condition

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using these two conditions, the problem is that the buttons are appearing both when only one should actually appear.

Ie If = `"currentState == 'pause'"` a button appears, otherwise If = `"currentState == 'pause' && 'taskdate'> 'data.key.deadline'"` the other button appears ... the problem is that both are appearing and not just 1. I think it's because the currentState is true in both ... How can I fix this?

**html**

```
 <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'cellTemplate'">
    <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn ClassPlay">
                <img style="width: 35px;" *ngIf="currentState=='pause' && taskdate <= data.key.deadline" src="./assets/play.svg">
                <img style="width: 35px;" *ngIf=" currentState=='pause' && taskdate > data.key.deadline" src="./assets/PlayRed.svg">
                <div *ngIf="currentState=='start'" src="./assets/playV.svg">
                  <img style="width: 38px;" *ngIf="currentRowIndex === data.rowIndex" src="./assets/playV.svg">
                  <img style="width: 38px;" *ngIf="currentRowIndex != data.rowIndex" src="./assets/PlayGrey.svg">
                </div>
     </button>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
taskdate = new Date();
```

[image]

Comment: Try this `*ngIf=" currentState=='pause' && taskdate > data?.key?.line"` with out single quote.

Comment: `'taskdate' > 'data.key.line'` will always be true because you're comparing the strings and not the variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add extra  `''` and add additional check on the 1st item `taskdate <= data.key.line`

Try this:

```
 <img style="width: 35px;" *ngIf="currentState == 'pause' && taskdate <= data.key.line" src="./assets/pl.svg">
 <img style="width: 35px;" *ngIf="currentState == 'pause' && taskdate > data.key.line" src="./assets/ap.svg">
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qnx6sq?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: I added 'taskdate' and ... perfect ! Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. Please upvote and accept the answer if it was helpful :)

Comment: So none of them appear :( My datetast is the same as this in component taskdate = new Date ();

I want to check if the current day is longer than the data line, it has a different button ... I must be doing something wrong :(

Comment: Check the demo, I added the conditions in a button.

Comment: My problem is that I get data.dealine as a string and am comparing it with a date :(

Comment: I added the photo with the date and format of my data.key.deadline

Comment: Check the modified answer.  `deadline = "2024-03-31T00:00:00";
  deadlineDate = new Date(this.deadline);`

Comment: `new Date(data.key.deadline)` should return you a date that you can compare with `taskdate`

Comment: Is there a way to make new date the deadline format?

Because dealine comes in an array, and it will be different from case to case

Comment: Check .map in the demo `let arr1: Array<any> = ["2024-03-31T00:00:00", "2018-03-31T00:00:00"];
    let arr2 = arr1.map(item => (item = new Date(item)));`

Answer (score 2):

There is no need extra single quotes. When you use `'taskdate'`, then it is evaluated as string. I believe, `taskdate` and `data?.key?.line` are variables:

```
<img style="width: 35px;"     
    *ngIf="currentState == 'pause' && (taskDate <= data?.key?.line)" 
    src="./assets/pl.svg">
<img style="width: 35px;" 
    *ngIf="currentState == 'pause' && (taskdate > data?.key?.line)" 
    src="./assets/ap.svg">
```

Comment: @downvoter what's reason to downvote? Could you say? It would be really helpful to improve my reply

Comment: It wasn't me and I even thanked you for your comment